# How to Display a field only once in a view

Tags: views

How to display field only once, please find the image.

[image]

How can we show image only once in a row.

PS:

1. We can add as attachment with image and another one with out image, but still there will be two queries ran, that I dont want.
2. We can make display:block for the first one and display:none for the rest. But this will load all images.

Answer (score 1):

In your view create two displays.

**The first display (the display you'll be using in your site)**
Add the title field only
Show 5 rows starting from 1

**The second display (a block for the first item)**
Add the title, image and excerpt from the body
Show only 1 row starting from 0

**Save the view**

**Edit the second view**
add a *Global: View area*, select the second display and (this is important!) add the field *for this page only*.

Comment: If we do the same as you mentioned, it will ran two queries one with first display and another one with second display, that I dont want because, in the same page I have lot more to display like the same page.

Comment: You should really just worry about that when performance becomes an issue.

Comment: Performance becomes almost always an issue, if you do not care about such things in advance.

Comment: Actually I have to use this in Menu and I around 30 menus with this type, So I have to think about the performance for sure.

Comment: You could try using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_content_cache

Comment: Or you could investigate this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15346450

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for that<sup>TM</sup>. [Views nodes split](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split) module does exactly what you're looking for.

> This module allows site administrators or builders to have a different view mode for the first nodes of a view result.

#### Update

This module works with view modes, not fields. That means, you should have at least 2 more view modes to be able to use this module for your approach. One view mode with image and one view mode without image.